# Having a lot of 'Module not found' errors for react project

Tags: javascript, reactjs, webpack, package.json

I was building my application no problem and all of a sudden I had a problem concerning all these modules not found. It is important to note that I am using react-rewired to handle webpack v5 and the polyfill issue.

Also, adding

`"browser": { "fs": false, "path": false, "os": false, "child_process": false },`

to my `package.json` file doesn't seem to work.

Here is the exact error I'm getting, any solution would be great.
Compiled with problems:X

> ERROR in ./node_modules/create-react-app/createReactApp.js 40:17-50
>
> Module not found: Error: Can't resolve 'child_process' in
> 'C:\Users\stefa\Documents\FSP\react_hooks_experiment\node_modules\create-react-app'
>
> ERROR in
> ./node_modules/create-react-app/node_modules/commander/index.js
> 6:12-42
>
> Module not found: Error: Can't resolve 'child_process' in
> 'C:\Users\stefa\Documents\FSP\react_hooks_experiment\node_modules\create-react-app\node_modules\commander'
>
> ERROR in
> ./node_modules/create-react-app/node_modules/commander/index.js
> 13:9-22
>
> Module not found: Error: Can't resolve 'fs' in
> 'C:\Users\stefa\Documents\FSP\react_hooks_experiment\node_modules\create-react-app\node_modules\commander'
>
> ERROR in ./node_modules/cross-spawn/index.js 3:11-35
>
> Module not found: Error: Can't resolve 'child_process' in
> 'C:\Users\stefa\Documents\FSP\react_hooks_experiment\node_modules\cross-spawn'
>
> ERROR in ./node_modules/cross-spawn/lib/util/readShebang.js 3:11-24
>
> Module not found: Error: Can't resolve 'fs' in
> 'C:\Users\stefa\Documents\FSP\react_hooks_experiment\node_modules\cross-spawn\lib\util'
>
> ERROR in ./node_modules/dns/node_modules/native-dns/lib/client.js
> 23:10-24
>
> Module not found: Error: Can't resolve 'net' in
> 'C:\Users\stefa\Documents\FSP\react_hooks_experiment\node_modules\dns\node_modules\native-dns\lib'
>
> ERROR in ./node_modules/dns/node_modules/native-dns/lib/pending.js
> 22:10-24
>
> Module not found: Error: Can't resolve 'net' in
> 'C:\Users\stefa\Documents\FSP\react_hooks_experiment\node_modules\dns\node_modules\native-dns\lib'
>
> ERROR in ./node_modules/dns/node_modules/native-dns/lib/platform.js
> 22:9-22
>
> Module not found: Error: Can't resolve 'fs' in
> 'C:\Users\stefa\Documents\FSP\react_hooks_experiment\node_modules\dns\node_modules\native-dns\lib'
>
> ERROR in ./node_modules/dns/node_modules/native-dns/lib/platform.js
> 24:10-24
>
> Module not found: Error: Can't resolve 'net' in
> 'C:\Users\stefa\Documents\FSP\react_hooks_experiment\node_modules\dns\node_modules\native-dns\lib'
>
> ERROR in ./node_modules/dns/node_modules/native-dns/lib/server.js
> 22:12-28
>
> Module not found: Error: Can't resolve 'dgram' in
> 'C:\Users\stefa\Documents\FSP\react_hooks_experiment\node_modules\dns\node_modules\native-dns\lib'
>
> ERROR in ./node_modules/dns/node_modules/native-dns/lib/server.js
> 24:10-24
>
> Module not found: Error: Can't resolve 'net' in
> 'C:\Users\stefa\Documents\FSP\react_hooks_experiment\node_modules\dns\node_modules\native-dns\lib'
>
> ERROR in ./node_modules/dns/node_modules/native-dns/lib/utils.js
> 20:12-28
>
> Module not found: Error: Can't resolve 'dgram' in
> 'C:\Users\stefa\Documents\FSP\react_hooks_experiment\node_modules\dns\node_modules\native-dns\lib'
>
> ERROR in ./node_modules/dns/node_modules/native-dns/lib/utils.js
> 23:10-24
>
> Module not found: Error: Can't resolve 'net' in
> 'C:\Users\stefa\Documents\FSP\react_hooks_experiment\node_modules\dns\node_modules\native-dns\lib'
>
> ERROR in ./node_modules/envinfo/dist/envinfo.js 469:14-27
>
> Module not found: Error: Can't resolve 'fs' in
> 'C:\Users\stefa\Documents\FSP\react_hooks_experiment\node_modules\envinfo\dist'
>
> ERROR in ./node_modules/envinfo/dist/envinfo.js 1670:14-38
>
> Module not found: Error: Can't resolve 'child_process' in
> 'C:\Users\stefa\Documents\FSP\react_hooks_experiment\node_modules\envinfo\dist'
>
> ERROR in ./node_modules/fs.realpath/index.js 8:9-22
>
> Module not found: Error: Can't resolve 'fs' in
> 'C:\Users\stefa\Documents\FSP\react_hooks_experiment\node_modules\fs.realpath'
>
> ERROR in ./node_modules/fs.realpath/old.js 25:9-22
>
> Module not found: Error: Can't resolve 'fs' in
> 'C:\Users\stefa\Documents\FSP\react_hooks_experiment\node_modules\fs.realpath'
>
> ERROR in ./node_modules/fstream-ignore/ignore.js 10:9-22
>
> Module not found: Error: Can't resolve 'fs' in
> 'C:\Users\stefa\Documents\FSP\react_hooks_experiment\node_modules\fstream-ignore'
>
> ERROR in ./node_modules/fstream/lib/proxy-writer.js 17:9-22
>
> Module not found: Error: Can't resolve 'fs' in
> 'C:\Users\stefa\Documents\FSP\react_hooks_experiment\node_modules\fstream\lib'
>
> ERROR in ./node_modules/fstream/node_modules/rimraf/rimraf.js 8:9-22
>
> Module not found: Error: Can't resolve 'fs' in
> 'C:\Users\stefa\Documents\FSP\react_hooks_experiment\node_modules\fstream\node_modules\rimraf'
>
> ERROR in ./node_modules/glob/common.js 13:9-22
>
> Module not found: Error: Can't resolve 'fs' in
> 'C:\Users\stefa\Documents\FSP\react_hooks_experiment\node_modules\glob'
>
> ERROR in ./node_modules/graceful-fs/graceful-fs.js 1:9-22
>
> Module not found: Error: Can't resolve 'fs' in
> 'C:\Users\stefa\Documents\FSP\react_hooks_experiment\node_modules\graceful-fs'
>
> ERROR in ./node_modules/isexe/index.js 1:9-22
>
> Module not found: Error: Can't resolve 'fs' in
> 'C:\Users\stefa\Documents\FSP\react_hooks_experiment\node_modules\isexe'
>
> ERROR in ./node_modules/isexe/mode.js 4:9-22
>
> Module not found: Error: Can't resolve 'fs' in
> 'C:\Users\stefa\Documents\FSP\react_hooks_experiment\node_modules\isexe'
>
> ERROR in ./node_modules/isexe/windows.js 4:9-22
>
> Module not found: Error: Can't resolve 'fs' in
> 'C:\Users\stefa\Documents\FSP\react_hooks_experiment\node_modules\isexe'
>
> ERROR in ./node_modules/jsonfile/index.js 6:8-21
>
> Module not found: Error: Can't resolve 'fs' in
> 'C:\Users\stefa\Documents\FSP\react_hooks_experiment\node_modules\jsonfile'
>
> ERROR in ./node_modules/mkdirp/index.js 3:9-22
>
> Module not found: Error: Can't resolve 'fs' in
> 'C:\Users\stefa\Documents\FSP\react_hooks_experiment\node_modules\mkdirp'
>
> ERROR in ./node_modules/native-dns-cache/lookup.js 20:12-28
>
> Module not found: Error: Can't resolve 'dgram' in
> 'C:\Users\stefa\Documents\FSP\react_hooks_experiment\node_modules\native-dns-cache'
>
> ERROR in ./node_modules/native-dns-cache/lookup.js 22:10-24
>
> Module not found: Error: Can't resolve 'net' in
> 'C:\Users\stefa\Documents\FSP\react_hooks_experiment\node_modules\native-dns-cache'
>
> ERROR in ./node_modules/prompts/dist/elements/prompt.js 3:17-36
>
> Module not found: Error: Can't resolve 'readline' in
> 'C:\Users\stefa\Documents\FSP\react_hooks_experiment\node_modules\prompts\dist\elements'
>
> ERROR in ./node_modules/prompts/lib/elements/prompt.js 3:17-36
>
> Module not found: Error: Can't resolve 'readline' in
> 'C:\Users\stefa\Documents\FSP\react_hooks_experiment\node_modules\prompts\lib\elements'
>
> ERROR in ./node_modules/rimraf/rimraf.js 5:11-24
>
> Module not found: Error: Can't resolve 'fs' in
> 'C:\Users\stefa\Documents\FSP\react_hooks_experiment\node_modules\rimraf'
>
> ERROR in ./node_modules/tar-pack/node_modules/rimraf/rimraf.js 8:9-22
>
> Module not found: Error: Can't resolve 'fs' in
> 'C:\Users\stefa\Documents\FSP\react_hooks_experiment\node_modules\tar-pack\node_modules\rimraf'
>
> ERROR in ./node_modules/tmp/lib/tmp.js 12:11-24
>
> Module not found: Error: Can't resolve 'fs' in
> 'C:\Users\stefa\Documents\FSP\react_hooks_experiment\node_modules\tmp\lib'
>
> ERROR in ./node_modules/uid-number/uid-number.js 7:20-44
>
> Module not found: Error: Can't resolve 'child_process' in
> 'C:\Users\stefa\Documents\FSP\react_hooks_experiment\node_modules\uid-number'
>
> ERROR in ./node_modules/zlib/lib/zlib.js 1:0-43
>
> Module not found: Error: Can't resolve './zlib_bindings' in
> 'C:\Users\stefa\Documents\FSP\react_hooks_experiment\node_modules\zlib\lib'

Answer (score -1):

Seems like you don't have node_modules folder content.

Open console in root of your project and type:

```
npm install
```

Comment: I've done that a bunch of times and it doesn't do anything